# Using Regex to match quoted string with embedded, non-escaped quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping, quotes

I am trying to match a string in the following pattern with a regex.

```
string text = "'Emma','The Last Leaf','Gulliver's travels'";
string pattern = @"'(.*?)',?";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text,pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
 {
    Console.WriteLine(match + " " + match.Index);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Captures[0]);
 }
```

This matches "Emma" and "The Last leaf" correctly, however the third match is "Gulliver". But the desired match is "Gulliver's travels". How can I build a regex for a patterns like this?

Comment: It is more linguistic problem :)

Comment: If you add a comma to your input string, you can get rid of the `?` in `,?` which is causing the false match. Is there no way you can get properly escaped input strings instead? What would you do if the book was actually named `"Gulliver','s travels"`?

Comment: You can handle nested characters with balanced grouping ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx ).  However, nested characters is not the worst of your problems.  The real problem is that the apostrophe in `Gulliver's` is not escaped.  This really makes the rules for the parser hard to define.

Comment: @Steve: I think the apostrophe is what the OP was talking about, and this isn't about nesting at all.  I removed the word "nested" from the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `,` is your delimiter, you can try changing your pattern like this. It should work.

```
string pattern = @"'(.*?)'(?:,|$)";
```

The way this works is, it looks for a single quote followed by a comma or end of the line.

Comment: +1 As it "works here", but see bzlm's (perhaps silly ;-) counter-example: `'Emma','The Last Leaf','Gulliver','s travels'` -- just keep in mind that regular expressions are relatively *fragile* beasts.

Comment: @pst OP's requirement is to match the portion of strings that are in between two single quotes and each of them separated ONLY by a comma. As far as I understand `,` is the only rescue here. Otherwise as you say this task requires a complex(or impossible) regex. Applying the above regex on the text you gave gives the expected output `Emma`,`The Last Leaf`,`Gulliver` and the meaningless `s travels`

Comment: +1. As long as the string you're parsing doesn't involve an odd combination of commas and apostrophes beyond what we've already seen, then this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can work `'(.*?)',|'(.*)'` as regular expression.

Comment: Try it with LINQPad (http://linqpad.org) -- *does* it work? What about if Gulliver's travels are first?

Comment: I've checked with expresso(http://www.ultrapico.com/) both versions(Gulliver at the end/at the beginning) seems to work

Comment: It works because alternation is ordered.  It always tries `'(.*?)',` first, and that matches all but the last item regardless of embedded apostrophes.  Rather elegant, really.

Comment: By the way, if you change it to `'(?<title>.*?)',|'(?<title>.*)'`, you can retrieve the desired portion by way of `Groups["title"]`, and not have to use program logic to figure out which group did the matching.

Comment: Missed the suggestion for expresso somehow. Its a helpful little tool. Thank you esunar

Comment: Yes, love Expresso! BTW, this answer works wonderfully. I needed to look for strings in a SQL statement, and it found just what I was expecting. Deceptively simple!

Answer (score 1):

you may consider to use look behind /look ahead:

```
 "(?<=^'|',').*?(?='$|',')"
```

**test with grep**:

```
kent$  echo "'Emma','The Last Leaf','Gulliver's travels'"|grep -Po "(?<=^'|',').*?(?='$|',')"
Emma
The Last Leaf
Gulliver's travels
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, if you have single-quote delimited strings and `Gulliver's` contains a single, unescaped quote there's no way to distinguish it from the end of a string. You could always just split it by commas and trim `'`s from either side but I'm not sure that's what you want:

```
string text = "'Emma','The Last Leaf','Gulliver's travels'";

foreach(string s in text.split(new char[] {','})) {
    Console.WriteLine(s.Trim('\''));
}
```

Comment: Technically, it can be distinguished from the end of a string because the quote isn't followed by a comma or is the last character in the input. :)

Comment: @bzlm: I think you have your own answer to that :)